# How to read a file up to second to last line

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am trying to read a file given in following format 
hello

```
{

    1--2
    2--3
    3--4

}
```

I only want to use integers given in the file and to do that i am using the following code

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%d--%d", &a, &b) != EOF)
    {   // do something here}
```

The problem  is that this is not working because it goes in to an infinite loop after reading first line  and if i remove first line it goes to an  infinite loop at the last line where it read `}` . 
So,how can do this in a proper way?

Comment: Why I got a negative vote someone can ask for more information.

Comment: @user1492793 stackoverflow.com induces psychotic tendencies to long term users :-) ... seriously, through a bit of Googling or reading you could have figured that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all else fails, RTFM:
fscanf: "This function return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure."
Meanwhile, EOF=-1 although in some stdio.h header files on some platforms it could be equal to zero.
You could either check that fscanf returns 0 or use `feof(fp)` to check that the end of file has been reached.